# Where does Windows load the code for imagepath-less services?

Tags: windows, windows-services

I've got a bunch of services of the form:

```
R3 NDProxy;NDIS Proxy; [x]
R3 Ntfs;Ntfs; [x]
R1 Null;Null; [x]
```

Where normally the value after the semicolon would be the svchost group (if any) and loaded binary for the file in question, such as

```
R2 nsi;Network Store Interface Service;LocalService->C:\Windows\System32\Nsisvc.dll [25600 2009-07-13 23:21:21 Microsoft Corporation]
```

I've ruled out a bug in my code by checking this against what Windows does internally (that is, with `sc.exe queryex` or similar tools and looking at the image path).

How does Windows find the code to load for these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples you listed aren't services but *drivers*. While they are managed by the same Service Control Manager, drivers are loaded from `*.sys` images using `ScLoadDeviceDriver()` and run in kernel-space.

If no `ImagePath` is given, the path defaults to **`%SystemRoot%\System32\Drivers\<name>.sys`**, such as `C:\WINDOWS\System32\Drivers\null.sys`.

This is documented in Microsoft [KB103000 "CurrentControlSet\Services Subkey Entries"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/103000), under *ImagePath* and *Type*.